# View holder Class in Android

Tags: android

This is a basic question. I was going through an official video by google regarding android. In it they used Viewholder class as

static class Viewholder{
    ImageView image;
    Textview text;
}

Would it be right to declare this class as static or view holder is used as static inner class.

I think suppose if its top level class then compiler will throw error while using static keyword with top level class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use static only if your ViewHolder is an inner class.