# Do we have to make new on Static class

Tags: java, android, static

While going through the documentation, i read some where that ViewHolder is a static class, but does it require to make new on static class?
In that example they have done new on it?, but according to the concept new should not be done on static class right?

Comment: static modifier on a class is a different concept to static modifier on a variable or method.http://www.techrepublic.com/article/explore-javas-static-nested-classes-and-inner-classes/5815620

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295735/view-holder-class-in-android

Comment: @Blundell thanks, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only construct classes four ways:

1. Using "new"
2. Using using Class.newInstance
3. Using a method / factory that internally uses new to create a new instance
4. Using object.clone, if it is supported

1 and 3 are by far the most used

Comment: But my question is, should we have to make new on static classes ?

Comment: yes you have to. A static class is for all intents the same as a class

Comment: But static class will have only static functions and variables right. so what is the purpose of new?

Comment: @LLL You are incorrect: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: You forgot at least one frequently used way: by deserializing a serialized object.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to a class as static, is not really the best expression, because it usually means that the classes does not have to be instantiated. But it also might depend on the context, which is would be needed to discussed first, because it is not given by your question.

Answer (score 1):

[This explains it well](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/explore-javas-static-nested-classes-and-inner-classes/5815620):

> The semantics for creating instances of nested classes can be
>   confusing. Below is a simple class that defines a static nested class
>   and an inner class. Pay special attention to the main method, where an
>   instance of each instance class is created.
>
> ```
>  // creating an instance of the enclosing class 
>  NestedClassTip nt = new NestedClassTip();
>
>
>  // creating an instance of the inner class requires 
>  // a reference to an instance of the enclosing class 
>  NestedClassTip.NestedOne nco = nt.new NestedOne();
>
>
>  // creating an instance of the static nested class 
>  // does not require an instance of the enclosing class 
>  NestedClassTip.NestedTwo nct = new NestedClassTip.NestedTwo();
>
>
>
> public class NestedClassTip {
> private String name = "instance name";
> private static String staticName = "static name";
>
> public static void main(String args[]) {
>     NestedClassTip nt = new NestedClassTip();
>
>     NestedClassTip.NestedOne nco = nt.new NestedOne();
>
>     NestedClassTip.NestedTwo nct = new NestedClassTip.NestedTwo();
> }
>
> class NestedOne {
>     NestedOne() {
>         System.out.println(name);
>         System.out.println(staticName);
>     }
> }
>
> static class NestedTwo {
>     NestedTwo() {
>         System.out.println(staticName);
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> Nested classes can be confusing, but once you understand their purpose
>   and get used to the semantics, there isn't a lot to them. If you'd
>   like to learn more about the details of nested classes, check out the
>   Java Language Specification.

Comment: So, for nested static class we should access using there parent class name, but for nested class we have to run new before using the members?

Comment: I think I get what your saying. Yes

Comment: But static class will have only static functions and variables right. so what is the purpose of new?

Comment: No it will have instance variables available to it. Like I said in your question comment, static modifier on class's is a different concept to static on a method. You need to go read up. http://tinyurl.com/cjlqkf9